# How to call a product list in a produt view Magento

Tags: php, magento, zend-framework

I need to display a product list in a product-view page. After a very intensive research i found that a block type="catalog/product_list" doesn't work if its called within a product-view page, so...what is the way to "universally" call a product list that can display in both category and product view pages???.
I can't code in view.phtml file, the product list i want to display is called by:

```
 {{block type="catalog/product_list" category_id="12" template="catalog/product/featured-products.phtml"}}
```

featured-products.phtml calls the product collection filter by the category id given:

```
<?php
    $_productCollection=$this->getLoadedProductCollection();
    $_helper = $this->helper('catalog/output');
    $cat_id = $this->category_id;
    $cat = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($cat_id);
?>
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by creating your own module. Try this. Here I am calling our module as `Listinview`.

Our module going to have following files.

**Module's configuration file**

**Location:app/code/local/Programmerrkt/Listinview/etc/config.xml**

```
<config>
<modules>
    <Programmerrkt_Listinview>
        <version>0.1.0</version>
    </Programmerrkt_Listinview>
</modules>
<frontend>
    <layout>
        <updates>
            <programmerrkt_listinview>
                <file>programmerrkt_listinview.xml</file>
            </programmerrkt_listinview>
        </updates>
    </layout>
</frontend>
<global>
    <blocks>
        <programmerrkt_listinview>
            <class>Programmerrkt_Listinview_Block</class>
        </programmerrkt_listinview>
    </blocks>
</global>
</config>
```

This file defines your modules configuration. It tells magento that it holds some blocks and some other stuffs.

**Location : app/etc/modules/Programmerrkt_Listinview.xml**

```
 <config>
<modules>
    <Programmerrkt_Listinview>
        <active>true</active>
        <codePool>local</codePool>
    </Programmerrkt_Listinview>
</modules>
</config>
```

It makes your module active and keep its version.

**Location: app/code/local/Programmerrkt/Listinview/Block/Catalog/Product/List.php**

```
 <?php

class Programmerrkt_Listinview_Block_Catalog_Product_List extends Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List
{

    /**
     * Default Category that is going to load
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $_defaultCategoryId = '12';

    /**
     * Default toolbar block name
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $_defaultToolbarBlock = 'catalog/product_list_toolbar';

    /**
     * Product Collection
     *
     * @var Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Collection_Abstract
     */
    protected $_productCollection;

    /**
     * Retrieve loaded category collection
     *
     * @return Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Collection_Abstract
     */
    protected function _getProductCollection()
    {
        if (is_null($this->_productCollection)) {

            $layer = $this->getLayer();
            $category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($this->_defaultCategoryId);
            if ($category->getId()) {
                    $origCategory = $layer->getCurrentCategory();
                    $layer->setCurrentCategory($category);
                    $this->addModelTags($category);
            }

            $this->_productCollection = $layer->getProductCollection();

            $this->prepareSortableFieldsByCategory($layer->getCurrentCategory());

            if ($origCategory) {
                $layer->setCurrentCategory($origCategory);
            }
        }

        return $this->_productCollection;
    }

    /*
        Calling method from view
    */
    public function getLoadedProductCollection()
    {
        return $this->_getProductCollection();
    }
}
```

This file defines the product collection method that we are going to use in our module. Since we need to load list according to a particular category, we are using a variable `$_defaultCategoryId` in order to define the required category to load.

**Note:** This file should extend `Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List`

**Location:`app/design/<your_package>/<your_theme>/layout/programmerrkt_listinview.xml`**

```
<layout>
<catalog_product_view>
       <reference name="content">
            <block type="programmerrkt_listinview/catalog_product_list" name="listinview_list" as="listinview_list" template="programmerrkt/listinview/catalog/product/list.phtml" />
       </reference>
</catalog_product_view>
</layout>
```

This is our module's layout definition. As you can see, it will add our custom block (that we are using to show our modules content) to `product view` page.

**Location:`app/design/frontend/<your_package>/<your_theme>/template/programmerrkt/listinview/catalog/product/list.phtml`**

```
<?php
    $_productCollection=$this->getLoadedProductCollection();
    $_helper = $this->helper('catalog/output');
?>
<?php if(!$_productCollection->count()): ?>
<p class="note-msg"><?php echo $this->__('There are no products matching the selection.') ?></p>
<?php else: ?>
<div class="category-products">
    <?php echo $this->getToolbarHtml() ?>
    <?php // List mode ?>
    <?php if($this->getMode()!='grid'): ?>
    <?php $_iterator = 0; ?>
    <ol class="products-list" id="products-list">
    <?php foreach ($_productCollection as $_product): ?>
        <li class="item<?php if( ++$_iterator == sizeof($_productCollection) ): ?> last<?php endif; ?>">
            <?php // Product Image ?>
            <a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->stripTags($this->getImageLabel($_product, 'small_image'), null, true) ?>" class="product-image"><img src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image')->resize(135); ?>" width="135" height="135" alt="<?php echo $this->stripTags($this->getImageLabel($_product, 'small_image'), null, true) ?>" /></a>
            <?php // Product description ?>
            <div class="product-shop">
                <div class="f-fix">
                    <?php $_productNameStripped = $this->stripTags($_product->getName(), null, true); ?>
                    <h2 class="product-name"><a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $_productNameStripped; ?>"><?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getName() , 'name'); ?></a></h2>
                    <?php if($_product->getRatingSummary()): ?>
                    <?php echo $this->getReviewsSummaryHtml($_product) ?>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                    <?php echo $this->getPriceHtml($_product, true) ?>
                    <?php if($_product->isSaleable()): ?>
                        <p><button type="button" title="<?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?>" class="button btn-cart" onclick="setLocation('<?php echo $this->getAddToCartUrl($_product) ?>')"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?></span></span></button></p>
                    <?php else: ?>
                        <p class="availability out-of-stock"><span><?php echo $this->__('Out of stock') ?></span></p>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                    <div class="desc std">
                        <?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getShortDescription(), 'short_description') ?>
                        <a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $_productNameStripped ?>" class="link-learn"><?php echo $this->__('Learn More') ?></a>
                    </div>
                    <ul class="add-to-links">
                        <?php if ($this->helper('wishlist')->isAllow()) : ?>
                            <li><a href="<?php echo $this->helper('wishlist')->getAddUrl($_product) ?>" class="link-wishlist"><?php echo $this->__('Add to Wishlist') ?></a></li>
                        <?php endif; ?>
                        <?php if($_compareUrl=$this->getAddToCompareUrl($_product)): ?>
                            <li><span class="separator">|</span> <a href="<?php echo $_compareUrl ?>" class="link-compare"><?php echo $this->__('Add to Compare') ?></a></li>
                        <?php endif; ?>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </li>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    </ol>
    <script type="text/javascript">decorateList('products-list', 'none-recursive')</script>

    <?php else: ?>

    <?php // Grid Mode ?>

    <?php $_collectionSize = $_productCollection->count() ?>
    <?php $_columnCount = $this->getColumnCount(); ?>
    <?php $i=0; foreach ($_productCollection as $_product): ?>
        <?php if ($i++%$_columnCount==0): ?>
        <ul class="products-grid">
        <?php endif ?>
            <li class="item<?php if(($i-1)%$_columnCount==0): ?> first<?php elseif($i%$_columnCount==0): ?> last<?php endif; ?>">
                <a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->stripTags($this->getImageLabel($_product, 'small_image'), null, true) ?>" class="product-image"><img src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image')->resize(135); ?>" width="135" height="135" alt="<?php echo $this->stripTags($this->getImageLabel($_product, 'small_image'), null, true) ?>" /></a>
                <h2 class="product-name"><a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->stripTags($_product->getName(), null, true) ?>"><?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getName(), 'name') ?></a></h2>
                <?php if($_product->getRatingSummary()): ?>
                <?php echo $this->getReviewsSummaryHtml($_product, 'short') ?>
                <?php endif; ?>
                <?php echo $this->getPriceHtml($_product, true) ?>
                <div class="actions">
                    <?php if($_product->isSaleable()): ?>
                        <button type="button" title="<?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?>" class="button btn-cart" onclick="setLocation('<?php echo $this->getAddToCartUrl($_product) ?>')"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?></span></span></button>
                    <?php else: ?>
                        <p class="availability out-of-stock"><span><?php echo $this->__('Out of stock') ?></span></p>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                    <ul class="add-to-links">
                        <?php if ($this->helper('wishlist')->isAllow()) : ?>
                            <li><a href="<?php echo $this->helper('wishlist')->getAddUrl($_product) ?>" class="link-wishlist"><?php echo $this->__('Add to Wishlist') ?></a></li>
                        <?php endif; ?>
                        <?php if($_compareUrl=$this->getAddToCompareUrl($_product)): ?>
                            <li><span class="separator">|</span> <a href="<?php echo $_compareUrl ?>" class="link-compare"><?php echo $this->__('Add to Compare') ?></a></li>
                        <?php endif; ?>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </li>
        <?php if ($i%$_columnCount==0 || $i==$_collectionSize): ?>
        </ul>
        <?php endif ?>
        <?php endforeach ?>
        <script type="text/javascript">decorateGeneric($$('ul.products-grid'), ['odd','even','first','last'])</script>
    <?php endif; ?>

    <div class="toolbar-bottom">
        <?php echo $this->getToolbarHtml() ?>
    </div>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

This content is actually rendering in frontend. Actually I just copied the content of `app/design/frontend/base/default/template/catalog/product/list.phtml` and pasted it in this file. Since we changed the method of loading product collection according to our need through controller file, now it will show all product in the desired category at the bottom section of `product view` page. Now you can do any changes to this phtml file in order to get your desired view.

Find this module here : https://github.com/progammer-rkt/Magent-Modules/tree/master/product-list-in-prdouct-view
I hope it will help. Thanks

Programmer_rkt