# Magento - Add Pagination/Toolbar using array of product ID's

Tags: magento, pagination, toolbar

I have a custom view that uses a range of conditional statements on a collection to narrow down a specific set of product ids. I then need to be able to display these with the pagination and toolbar present

```
// create product collection
$_category  = $this->getCurrentCategory();  
$collection = $_category->getProductCollection();
Mage::getModel('catalog/layer')->prepareProductCollection($collection);

//  create empty array for product id's
$ids = array();

// if and else conditions on collection for each
foreach($collection as $_product){
    $cats = $_product->getCategoryIds();
    if (condition 1 == ...){
        if (condition 2 == ...){
        } 
        else if (condition 3 == ...) {
        }
    } 
}

// end up with final array of product ids
$ids
```

How can i take these product ids and add the toolbar and pagination to it (like a normal view?) I've simplified the above code so it's clearer as I had a lot of irrelevant code in there so hopefully it makes sense

Answer (score 0):

See my answer on this [**THREAD**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24070402/how-to-call-a-product-list-in-a-produt-view-magento/24075053#24075053). It clearly explains how to display a list page inside a view page. In your case you can alter the method `_getProductCollection()` in the block and put your code inside that method.

So the method should look like this.

```
public function _getProductCollection()
{
    //Your filtering comes here
    // need to store all product ids into an array.
    //here taking a demo array. Put your product Id array instead of that.
    $productIds = array(140,141,142,143,144);
    $attributes=Mage::getSingleton('catalog/config')->getProductAttributes();
    $collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
                        ->getCollection()               
                        ->addAttributeToFilter('entity_id', array('in' => $productIds))
                        ->addAttributeToSelect($attributes)
                        ->load();
    return $collection;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 step 1: In app/code/local/Mage/catalog/product/newall.php

    create block file that extend to Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List



<?php

class Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_Newall extends Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List
{

   protected function _getProductCollection()
   {
   if (is_null($this->_productCollection)) {
      $todayDate  = Mage::app()->getLocale()->date()->toString(Varien_Date::DATETIME_INTERNAL_FORMAT);

      $collection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection');
      $collection->setVisibility(Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_visibility')->getVisibleInCatalogIds());

      $collection = $this->_addProductAttributesAndPrices($collection)
         ->addStoreFilter()
         ->addAttributeToFilter('news_from_date', array('date' => true, 'to' => $todayDate))
         ->addAttributeToFilter('news_to_date', array('or'=> array(
            0 => array('date' => true, 'from' => $todayDate),
            1 => array('is' => new Zend_Db_Expr('null')))
         ), 'left')
         ->addAttributeToSort('news_from_date', 'desc')
         ->setPageSize($this->get_prod_count())
         ->setCurPage($this->get_cur_page());

      $this->setProductCollection($collection);
    }
      return $collection;
   }  

}


Step 2 : In Layout File or any cms Page Add he following code

<reference name="content">
   <block type="catalog/product_newall" name="product_new" template="catalog/product/list.phtml">
    <block type="catalog/product_list_toolbar" name="product_list_toolbar" template="catalog/product /list/toolbar.phtml">
         <block type="page/html_pager" name="product_list_toolbar_pager"/>
      </block>
     <action method="setToolbarBlockName"><name>product_list_toolbar</name></action>
   </block>
</reference>
```